# Get table name from string query irrespective of CRUD operation

Tags: java, sql-parser, jsqlparser

I have string like below. I have to get all table name from this.

```
 select SEQ_NO,CODE,CD_NAME,CD_TYPE,CD_CITY,CDS_STATUS,CDS_SUBSTATUS,  
 to_char(CDS_LAST_MOD_DATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') as CDS_LAST_MOD_DATE   from  
 company_details left outer join on company_details_status where  
 cd_seq_no=cds_seq_no,CODE=(select CODE from company_details where cd_seq_no='1' )  order by CDS_LAST_MOD_DATE.
```

```
Insert into table1 value(?,?)
Insert into table1 (col1,col2) values(?,?)
```

How to get table name for insert query like above.

Comment: Your `SELECT` query won't even run, because it has typos.  If you're looking for a general solution here, you'll need to write a rudimentary parser to handle SQL code.

Comment: i wrote for sample only its my production level query it wont run everywhere.I need solution whatever query string is given i need corresponding table names

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code which hints at how you might approach this problem.  It uses a regex matcher with the following pattern:

```
FROM\s+(\S+)|JOIN\s+(\S+)|INSERT\s+INTO\s+(\S+)
```

The aim here is to capture table names whenever they occur in select statements (after `FROM` and `JOIN`), or in insert statements (after `INSERT INTO`).  Note that the pattern uses an alternation with three capture groups.

```
String query =  "SELECT a.col1, b.col2 FROM tableA a INNER JOIN tableB b ";
       query += "ON a.key = b.key; INSERT INTO tableC (col1) VALUES ('hello')";
String pattern = "FROM\\s+(\\S+)|JOIN\\s+(\\S+)|INSERT\\s+INTO\\s+(\\S+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = r.matcher(query);
while (m.find()) {
    String match = m.group(1) != null ? m.group(1) :
        (m.group(2) != null ? m.group(2) : m.group(3));
    System.out.println(match);
}

tableA
tableB
tableC
```

### Demo

Obviously there are many edge cases I may have missed.  In general, for a complete solution you might have to write an actual SQL parser.  For simple select and insert queries, this could be a good starting point.

Comment: If i add sub query mean above regx will give that.I tried with ZQL parser but cannt use it properly and tried with JSqlParser jar itself TableNameFinder class missing cannot use. Thats y i posted here

Comment: Your comment does not seem to be really directed at my answer.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING AT ME?  DO YOU HAZ THA CODEZ?

Comment: Asking for full SQL parser code is beyond the scope of a single question.